# accessing foreign key in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In the example below, I have a model `Proof` which contains a foreign key to the model `Option`.
I want to list all the options in my template along with their respective proofs. How would I go about making the relevant joins in django? I tried using a `_set.all()` method but that doesn't seem to work on a queryset, only on a single listing.

Thanks for your help :)

Models.py

```
class Option(TimeStampActivate):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Proof(TimeStampActivate):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    link = models.URLField()
```

View.py

```
options = Option.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this was supposed to work in template with `options = Option.objects.all()` in view().

```
{% for option in options %}
    {{option}}
    {% for proof in option.proof_set.all %}
        {{proof}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! 
But doing the look up this way, is there a new sql lookup run for every item in the loop? Or is the join just done once?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think there won't be a new lookup for every item (this is done within template context using results obtained from your query in a view, so it won't hit the database). Even in a view `Option.objects.all()` does not hit the database at first. Check [queryset API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) for more info.

Comment: [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) can boost performance in retrieving related objects. Note: prefetch related work in Django-1.4

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a fancy way to query and get what you want, but how about creating a dictionary of the proofs keyed by the option?

```
from collections import defaultdict
proofs = Proof.objects.all()
options = defaultdict(list)
for p in proofs:
    options[p.option].append(p)
```